# What is the harpsichord music being played at the school?

Tags: music, flip-flappers

In episode 5 of *Flip Flappers*, Papika and Cocona end up in what Yayaka later reveals to be a day-long time loop. (This does not come as a surprise: prior to the announcement, we see Papika and Cocona repeat what is implied to the exact same routine every day, and the doll whose head Cocona moves in the evening always faces its original direction in the morning.)

One of the events of this repeated day is a music lesson: Papika and Cocona sit in a circle with some other students around some candles, and two students are playing a keyboard instrument. In the background, harpsichord music starts playing and runs until the bedroom scene. This occurs in each instance of the routine (music, library, tea, embroidery) that we see prior to Yayaka's confrontation with Cocona.

What is the music being played? (If it is an original composition for the anime, is there a track title that someone can point me to? If it isn't, what is the title and composer of the excerpted piece?)

Comment: Update: I haven't had any luck either with listening to the previews [here](https://www.amazon.co.jp/TV%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1%E3%80%8E%E3%83%95%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%83%95%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA%E3%80%8F%E3%82%AA%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B8%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF-MAS/dp/B01MDMAQEL/) (at least the openings didn't match) or with running the beginning of the sequence through the Musipedia search engine.

Answer (score 0):

It's [Keith Jarret's interpretation of Johann Sebastian Bach's Prelude and Fugue n. 12 in F moll](https://youtu.be/sWU5qYaF3nI) on his album [Das Wohltemperierte Klavier, Buch II](https://youtu.be/m6jrDtXNn_s). The piece is not included on the OST.

Comment: I listened to both the BWV prelude and fugue, and neither sounds like what appears in that loop sequence. I’ll take a look at the rest of the Well-Tempered Clavier though.